# After converting mobile to beacon, is it possible to scan other beacons?

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

Am gonna developing one which app converts mobile to beacon using beacon transmission. My question is after converting to beacon, wether scanning other beacon is possible in same app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an Android mobile app can transmit as a beacon and scan for beacons at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I have checked with sample. Its working. But MAC id not correct while transamitting. It generating random MAC ID each time while transmitting. Is it possible to transmit unique MAC ID?

Comment: This is a privacy feature of Android.  It randomizes the Mac on Bluetooth LE transmission so that no receiver will be able to determine your unique Bluetooth MAC identifier.  There is no way to control this from the API.  If you need to uniquely identify the device, you may make a readable BLE characteristic in a Gatt service that allows reading the MAC address or other unique identifier.  You could even transmit the actual MAC in the beacon identifier as part of the advertisement.  But doing this you defeat the privacy protections, so do so wisely.